# ASP.Net web app using BizTalk 2009

Tags: asp.net, biztalk

I am building a web app for which I need a bit of guidance in design. We have one application from vendor which uses SQL Server 2005 as database. Let’s say vendor’s application provides details on Order etc.

The web app that I am building will have its own database (SQL Server 2005). For my application to get any details about “Orders”, it needs to go thru BizTalk.  So the flow would as below

- a. User will type the order id in
  TextBox (Web App), click submit
  button.
- b. Biztalk needs to receive this
  order id, give this order id to
  Vendor’s SQL Server Database to
  retrieve the order details.
- c. Order details should be sent back
  to the Web App.
- d. I also want to make sure that this
  whole process (from a-c ) should be
  real quick, as we do    postback to
  retrieve the information from
  database.

Comment: Ideally you don't want BizTalk specifically tied to UI events of an application as it provides lots of overhead for just simple request/response pattern your needing.

Answer (score 3):

Adding BizTalk into the application flow that you described will add a lot of overhead. It would be simpler, run faster, and likely be cheaper to create a WCF service that sits between the web app and the vendor's database for Orders.

---

BizTalk provides reliable messaging. So the application flow, as described in the question, would look something like this:

1. Web App Submit/Postback (IIS)
2. BizTalk Receive (IIS or MSMQ or whatever adapter you want)
3. BizTalk SQL Database
4. BizTalk Send (Request)
5. SQL Server Query Result
6. BizTalk Receive (Response)
7. BizTalk Database
8. BizTalk Send
9. Web App Receives Response (IIS)

With that you get message persistence and reliability. If something breaks (e.g., the vendor's SQL database is offline) there will be a suspended message in BizTalk and the web app will time out waiting for the synchronous response from BizTalk. Or you could also capture the error and pass it back to the web app using BizTalk and add more overhead to the process.

If you are only *getting* existing orders (i.e., not creating/updating/deleting orders), then you do not need your messages/transactions to be so reliable or expensive. If something fails the user will see an error and just submit again until it works (you can log the errors on the server to notify an admin, if desired).

Using something like a [WCF service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324)—perhaps with [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) sitting atop the vendor's database—would still allow you to abstract the vendor's database from your web app and also provide:

- Faster response times
- No additional infrastructure (e.g., additional BizTalk services and SQL Server databases) since just runs in IIS
- Less additional training for a developer who is already familiar with ASP.NET and not with BizTalk

Answer (score 2):

This is really not an appropriate use for BizTalk.  It would be more appropriate to write a WCF Serivce on your web server to expose the SQL Data.  Have the app call the service directly.  This will meet your requirement for real quick.  BizTalk's reliable messaging comes at a cost... peristence points.  By the time you request and receive the data, BizTalk will be writing and reading the data to the database many times.  If the user was submitting an order, BizTalk would be preferrable for this as once the web app passes the order to BizTalk, you're guaranteed it will not be lost.

As another quick note, I am not up to date on all the cool new features in SQL Server, but I believe there is a way to have SQL exposes your data directly as a web service for consumption by your web app.